# How do I set 'global' as default gemset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

In RVM every time I restart it says gems aren't found, because all of them are installed in my 'global' gemset.

How can I just set this to be the default so I don't need to switch to that gemset everytime?

Answer (score 0):

I actually looked through documentation for some time and didn't see anything, but I found this from stack overflow by searching a bunch of different things.

First run `rvm list` to see your rubies

Then run `rvm gemset list` to see your gemsets

Finally, run `rvm use <desired-ruby-version>@<gemset> --default`

For example:

`rvm use ruby-1.9.3-head@global --default`

Comment: There is still something wrong here; gems in the global gemset should be visible no matter what gemset is in "use".